# Pass a string to $_POST

Tags: php, string, post

I have several radiobutton arrays.
They're named awardLevel0[] , awardLevel1[] , awardLevel2[], and so on, generated dynamically by the user.
I want to know if this function will work to get their total sum values.

```
function awardCheck () {
    $exist = true;
    $num = 0;
    $endsum = 0;
    while ($exist)
    {
        $names = "awardLevel" . $num;
        $awardLev = $_POST[$names];
        if (empty($awardLev)) {
            $exist = false;
            return $endsum;
        }
        else 
            $endsum = $endsum + $awardLev;
        $num++;
    }
    return $endsum;
}
```

**When I run the code above, it gives me an error at  $endsum = $endsum + $awardLev; saying i'm using unspported operand types. When I remove $awardLev, it runs without that error.**

Is it possible to pass a variable containg a string to $_POST like

```
$postname = "awardLevel2";
$awardLev = $_POST[$postname];
```

Comment: What happens when you run that?

Comment: What happens when you run your function?  Does it work as you intended?

Comment: yes $_POST[$stringvariable] is perfectly ok

Comment: @Bryan When I run my function it gives me an error at
            '$endsum = $endsum + $awardLev;'

With unsupported operand types

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can absolutely do that, but just a note:

With the `[]` syntax in the POST values, you get an array back rather than a string.  You could use this to your advantage and even `array_sum` the `_POST[awardLevel]` values if you just drop the number, but I'm not sure if that would work for you.

I missed your syntax error (btw post any errors immediately next time).

Since `awardLev` is an array, you can only use `+` with another array, not with an integer.  Just use

```
$endsum += $awardLev[0]
```

instead.  OR if you are expecting multiple values per `awardLev`:

```
$endsum += array_sum($awardLev);
```

Comment: I edited the post with what happens when I actually run the code.

Comment: Thank you, adding only the first element of the array fixed the problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

A usefull fact when you have a lot of known components and you want to create dynamic variables with the name of your post variables is doing some like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
    $$key = $value;
}
```

For example, if you have an item like

```
<textarea name="postText"></textarea>
```

You will have a variable called "postText"

Comment: I advise against this.  It's clever, but *too* clever.  Using arrays is much clearer than using variables of variables.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this..??

```
$endsum = $endsum.$awardLev;
```